# Prediction on new data after pickling on regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, linear-regression

I have created ridge regression model to predict sales of an item say X. My final model contains around 180 features. I have pickled this model and now I want to see how model I created is performing on new data set containing same features as present in different model but on different timeframe.
I have to pass entire new dataset(dataframe) into existing model and check relevant score say r-square or any other score relevant to regression model.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
# loading library
import pickle

    with open('ridge_model', 'wb') as p:
        pickle.dump(ridge, p)
    
    y_test = df.pop('Target')
    x_test = df
    
    # load saved model
    with open('ridge_model' , 'rb') as p:
        new_reg = pickle.load(p)
    
    r_squared = new_reg.score(x_test,y_test)
    print(r-squared)
```

Here ridge is the regression model I created

df is the  new data on which prediction needs to be done

y_test contains target variable
x_test contains features in dataset except target variable

I want to understand:

1. Can we pass entire new data set onto existing model for prediction and
   see how model is performing or not?
2. `r_squared = new_reg.score(x_test,y_test)` in this line does .score calculates r-square as
   calculated on existing model or any other score it calculates?

Comment: What do you mean "calculated on existing model or any other score it calculates."?

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (tl;dr: **never**).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy "calculated on existing model  means I used r-squared values while checking the performance of existing model so when we use .score does it gives            
r-square value or any other score.

Comment: The return value of .score is specified on the documentation of your model, assuming you use scikit-learn, you did not specify any framework.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes I used scikit learn package and created ridge  regression model

Comment: Then I suggest you check the sklearn documentation about what .score returns for that model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy  Can you let me know if we can pass entire new dataset while doing prediction on new data using existing model

Comment: Thats the whole point of doing predictions, to pass new data.